# Hide a div with multiple classes and no id with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide

We would like to hide the div with classes k-header k-grid-toolbar, which is a child div of g-m div:

```
<div id="g-m" data-controllername="b-p-d" data-create="false" data-edit="false" data-update-url="/BPD/BPDPrint.aspx" data-delete="false" data-export="false" data-role="extendedgrid2" class="k-grid k-widget" style="height: 230px;">

<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar">
```

We tried the followings, but did not get any results:

```
1. $('div.k-header.k-grid-toolbar').hide();
2. $("div.k-header.k-grid-toolbar:not([id])").hide();
3. $('#g-m').find(".k-grid-toolbar").hide();
```

Comment: Your first try should have worked though.

Comment: That mean you've an error elsewhere in your code.

Comment: umm is there a reason why you cant do it in css - display:none?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: did you wrap your jquery in document ready?

Comment: You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/q697ws4g/ -- so the other posts are correct-- there is some other error in your code.

Comment: $('div.k-header.k-grid-toolbar').hide(); works for me: Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p5xmjda0. Chrome inspector shows display: "none"

Answer (score 0):

Your number 1 solution should work perfectly well, but your sample html is incomplete without the closing tags. In the example below I added a border around your `div#g-m` and added a delay in order to see the child div before it hides. At least in your text you said the div with the classes `.k-header .k-grid-toolbar` is a child of `#g-m`

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $('div.k-header.k-grid-toolbar').hide();
}, 2000);
```

```css
#g-m{border: 2px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="g-m" data-controllername="b-p-d" data-create="false" data-edit="false" data-update-url="/BPD/BPDPrint.aspx" data-delete="false" data-export="false" data-role="extendedgrid2" class="k-grid k-widget" style="height: 230px;">

 <div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar"> div to hide </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't posted the part of your HTML code, as by looking at your code, you're not closing the `div` tags properly. According to your first try, it seems to be working, please have a look on the code below!

> **Note:** As I'm using `$(function(){ ... });` here...thats why hidden div isn't loading in the output, because the script is running as soon as page loads

```js
// Using page on load here...thats why hidden div isn't loading in the output, because the script is running as soon as page loads

$(function(e){

  $('div.k-header.k-grid-toolbar').hide();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="g-m" data-controllername="b-p-d" data-create="false" data-edit="false" data-update-url="/BPD/BPDPrint.aspx" data-delete="false" data-export="false" data-role="extendedgrid2" class="k-grid k-widget" style="height: 230px;">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div> <!-- Close this div here -->

<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar">
  The div to get hidden
</div> <!-- Close this div here -->
```

Hope this helps!